# GGPlots legend colors more clear

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar

Is there any way  I can make these colour more obvious in my `geom_bar` `ggplot` graph? In particular the blue / green ones. Also is there a way to have a white line/space between the colors as the top and bottom ones do?

[image]

Comment: You could try another palette using for example [ggthemr](https://github.com/cttobin/ggthemr)

Comment: For white line, try adding `colour = "white"` inside your `geom_bar()`?

Comment: geom_bar (colour = "white")  doesn't work

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

`colour = "white"` should help you differentiate the colours. If not, then increase `size=2`. For example:

```
library(vcd)
data(Arthritis)
ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = Treatment, fill = Improved)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "white", size=2)
```

[image]